# Do a string split for more than one row in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, char, strsplit

I have written a for loop in which to split 5000 rows accordingly along each of the columns that they are in.

Example of the cell array that contains those rows:
[image]

From that picture, i would like to split each row accordingly along their respective columns of that row starting from the first column to the end.

This is the code that i have written:

```
for i = pdbindex(:,1)

    clean_pdb = regexprep(pdbindex, ':', ' '); % removes the colon (:) from the array and replaces it with a whitespace
    pdb2char = char(clean_pdb); % converts the cell array into a character array
    pdb2split = strsplit(pdb2char, ' '); % does a split based on the character array followed by a delimiter, which is the white space

end
```

I have used Regular Expressions to replace the colons (:), with a whitespace. However, it is throwing me an error stating `Input strings must have one row.`. I don't know how to solve this.

Please advise.

Comment: Looks like your first row is empty.  Try `for i = pdbindex(2:end,1)`.

Comment: My apologies. I have done the amendments to my cell array. I had moved my mouse cursor over the row and hit enter after i had tested the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this like this:

```
%Some sample data
data = {'1 : 2  :  3 :4: 5: 6';'7 :8 : 9: 10 :11 :12'};
```

The Divide all the rows based on delimiters (a delimiter is any combinations of white space and ":")

```
splitData = regexp(data,'[\s\:]*','split')
```

Now your split data can be read out as

```
example = splitData{row}{column};
```

Most likely you will want to convert this to numbers (not strings).  You can do this one row at a time like this:

```
numericRow = num2double(splitData{rowNumber});
```